# Definite integral of a piece-wise function

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, random-variables

I have a random variable $X$ with a probability density function and I want to solve for $a$ for the function to be legal and then to calculate $\Pr\{X<1.5\}$.

$$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a^x\ln(a) & \quad 1\leq x \leq 2 \\
            0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

To solve for $a$ :

$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)\,dx=\int^{2}_{1} a^x\ln(a)\,dx=\ln(a)\frac{a^x}{\ln(a)}\Biggr|^2_1 =a^2-a=1$$ (from the definition of the pdf).

After solving the equation $a=1.618$.

Now to solve for $\Pr\{X<1.5\}$ I'm having trouble calculating the integral after plugging in $a$:

$$F(x)=\int^{x}_{-\infty} f(y)\,dy=\int^{x}_{1} (1.618)^y\ln(1.618)\,dy$$

Answer (score 1):

Your $a$ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), $\phi$.  We don't need to know this, but the golden ratio is worth noticing.

You have already shown that 
$$  \int_1^x a^y \ln a \,\mathrm{d}y = a^x - a^1  \text{,}  $$
so why not use it?  $\phi^{3/2} - \phi$ is just some number near $0.4$.

Comment: So $Pr\{X<1.5\}=F(1.5)=a^{3/2}-a$ where $a=1.618$?

Comment: When you chose $a$ to normalize your PDF, where is the only place you used the "$2$" in "$\int_1^2$"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, in the first part where i solved for $a$ ?